How to use Powershell to batch rename images to delete all of filename after the first space in existing name
Needing to rename a LOT of image files. Repeating names is not an issue as they were given numbers at the beginning of name and are all unique. What I need is to delete all the unnecessary mess after the initial number sequence.
8274 Blah whatever unimportant_trash.jpg
Needs to just be
8274.jpg
I know powershell will do this, I just don't know how to code it, because I don't code.
Just need to remove everything after the initial space in the file names.
Also, talk like I'm a coding idiot, because...well... I just don't know code speak. Reading all the forums isn't getting me anywhere.
TIA
Any codes I have found don't do what I need and I can't get it to point to the folder I need either.

StackOverflow community is here to help you find a solution, not just bluntly give it to you. You probably did some research, found Powershell commands that do some part of what you are trying to achieve. Let us know what you have tried so far :)

Here, with a bit of explaining comments.
-replace uses regular expressions to perform its magic in reducing 99 problems to 100, you can read more about them here
Also, it's generally though as polite to at least attempt yourself and post the code and the error\results: it means you TRIED(and usually learned something out of said trying, if not immediately useful for your current problem).
# Get all items in the directory $Paty that are -File and match the -Filter.   
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -file -filter '*.jpg' | 
    # rename them with the consecutive numbers starting from the begin of
    # their names plus the extension, removing everything else.   
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName -replace '(^\d+).*', ('$1{0}' -f $_.Extension) } 

